# Variable at the end of HTML

Tags: sql-server

Need to be able to put a variable in this url. Is that possible?

N'http://loanreview/LoanLogin/Loan/Edit/Variable Here!!"> Link to Item' +

We are creating a trigger on a table and in the trigger email we want to send a link to the item that was changed and created the trigger. So the url is http://loanreview/LoanLogin/Loan/Edit and we want to add /the loan id variable to the end

Please see the whole trigger below:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Status_Change6]
ON [dbo].[Loan_Details]
after update
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
  DECLARE @subject NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
    DECLARE @recipients varchar(255);
    DECLARE @ID int;




    SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H2>Loan Servicing Status Changed to Booking</H2>' +
    N'<a href=""http://loanreview/LoanLogin/Loan/Edit/6686"> Link to Item</a>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Loan ID</th>' +
    N'<th>Borrower Name</th>' +
    N'<th>Loan Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Team Leader</th></tr>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT 
      td = i.loan_id,       '',
          td = cm.cust_name ,       '',
          td = case when ld.loan_number IS null then ' ' else ld.LOAN_NUMBER end,       '',                  
          td = e.FAMILIAR_NAME,       ''  


              FROM inserted i inner join deleted d 
              on i.LOAN_ID = d.Loan_ID and i.STATUS <> d.STATUS and i.STATUS = 4 and d.STATUS <>4
        inner join Status s  on i.STATUS = s.Status_ID 
        inner join Loan_Details ld on i.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id and ld.LOAN_ID = d.LOAN_ID
        and ld.STATUS = s.Status_ID
        inner join Employee e on ld.OFFICER = e.EMP_ID
        inner join REL_CUST rc on rc.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id
        inner join Customer_Master cm on cm.CUST_ID = rc.CUST_ID and cm.CUST_ID = rc.REL_TRAN_ID 
        and relationship_id = 1

        WHERE (i.STATUS <> d.STATUS and i.STATUS = 4 and d.STATUS <>4)
         and relationship_id = 1 

              ORDER BY i.loan_id ASC
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) 
    +
    N'</table>' ;



    SET @subject = 
     CAST ( ( SELECT  i.loan_id,       '', cm.cust_name,  ld.loan_number,  e.FAMILIAR_NAME
              FROM inserted i inner join deleted d on i.LOAN_ID = d.Loan_ID and i.STATUS = 4
        inner join Status s  on i.STATUS = s.Status_ID 
        inner join Loan_Details ld on i.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id and ld.LOAN_ID = d.LOAN_ID
        and ld.STATUS = s.Status_ID
        inner join Employee e on ld.OFFICER = e.EMP_ID
        inner join REL_CUST rc on rc.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id
        inner join Customer_Master cm on cm.CUST_ID = rc.CUST_ID and cm.CUST_ID = rc.REL_TRAN_ID 
        and relationship_id = 1

        WHERE i.STATUS <> d.STATUS and i.STATUS = 4 and relationship_id = 1 and d.STATUS <>4
              ORDER BY i.loan_id ASC
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'
  ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )


   SET @recipients = (select user_name  + '@southernfirst.com' + ';'from inserted i inner join Employee e 
    on i.loan_admin = e.EMP_ID)
   SET @ID = (select loan_id from inserted)
   --SET @subject =  @ID 


    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM inserted i inner join deleted d 
              on i.LOAN_ID = d.Loan_ID and i.STATUS <> d.STATUS and i.STATUS = 4 and d.STATUS <>4
        inner join Status s  on i.STATUS = s.Status_ID 
        inner join Loan_Details ld on i.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id and ld.LOAN_ID = d.LOAN_ID
        and ld.STATUS = s.Status_ID
        inner join Employee e on ld.OFFICER = e.EMP_ID
        inner join REL_CUST rc on rc.LOAN_ID = ld.loan_id
        inner join Customer_Master cm on cm.CUST_ID = rc.CUST_ID and cm.CUST_ID = rc.REL_TRAN_ID 
        and relationship_id = 1

        WHERE (i.STATUS <> d.STATUS and i.STATUS = 4 and d.STATUS <>4)
         and relationship_id = 1 )



    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'Navigator Email',
          @subject =  @subject,
          @body = @tableHTML,
          @body_format = 'HTML',
          @recipients = @recipients


    END
END
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, welcome to DBA.SE. It is very unclear what you're asking for here. Can you try explaining more? What does your final desired result look like, what SQL have you tried so far, and what variables are you using?

Comment: thanks for the reply and welcome! I have edited my orginal post with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a special placeholder string in your base HTML

```
SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H2>Loan Servicing Status Changed to Booking</H2>' +
    N'<a href=""http://loanreview/LoanLogin/Loan/Edit/[LoadIdPlaceHolder]"> Link to Item</a>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Loan ID</th>' +
    N'<th>Borrower Name</th>' +
    N'<th>Loan Number</th>' +
    N'<th>Team Leader</th></tr>' +
```

And at the very end of your trigger just before you send the email, use `REPLACE` to change the [LoadIdPlaceHolder]  string with your Loanid variable that was initialized here

```
SET @ID = (select loan_id from inserted)
```

---

```
BEGIN
    SET @tableHTML = REPLACE(@tableHTML,'[LoanIdPlaceHolder]',convert(varchar(20),@ID)
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'Navigator Email',
      @subject =  @subject,
      @body = @tableHTML,
      @body_format = 'HTML',
      @recipients = @recipients


END
```

Comment: Scott you are a gentleman and a scholar! It is working! Next beer is on me :)